# Add comma after journal title and "new series" (spelled out in full) in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, code-review

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{sarfraz}.

Read \textcite{shore}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get this reference list:

> Sarfraz, M. and M. F. A. Razzak (2002). “Technical section: An algorithm for automatic capturing of the font outlines”. In: *Computers and Graphics* 26.5, pp. 795–804. issn: 0097-8493.
>
> Shore, Bradd (Mar. 1991). “Twice-Born, Once Conceived. Meaning Construction and Cultural Cognition”. In: *American Anthropologist.* New ser. 93.1, pp. 9–27.

But to satisfy the requirements of my style guide I need to use comma (not period) after journal title. "New ser." also needs to be spelled out in full as "new series" with a comma after it.

This is my code change to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{newseries = {new series}}
\newbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}

Read \textcite{sarfraz}.

Read \textcite{shore}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output now is like this:

> Sarfraz, M. and M. F. A. Razzak (2002). “Technical section: An algorithm for automatic capturing of the font outlines”. In: *Computers and Graphics,* 26.5, pp. 795–804. issn: 0097-8493.
>
> Shore, Bradd (Mar. 1991). “Twice-Born, Once Conceived. Meaning Construction and Cultural Cognition”. In: *American Anthropologist,* new series, 93.1, pp. 9–27.

Is this the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have shown is a valid and idiomatic way to solve this.

---

Since the long string for `newseries` is already, "new series" instead of redefining the string, you could either tell `biblatex` to use long strings everywhere with `abbreviate=false,` (which will affect other strings as well - probably not what you want) or force the long form only here with `\biblstring` instead of `\bibstring` in the field format for `series`.

If you use `biblatex-ext`, you don't need to redefine `journal+issuetitle`, you can just change `\jourvoldelim` and `\jourserdelim`.

So an alternative would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{series}{% series of a journal
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\mkbibordseries{#1}~\biblstring{jourser}}
    {\ifbibstring{#1}{\biblstring{#1}}{#1}}}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\jourserdelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Read \textcite{sarfraz}.

Read \textcite{shore}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sarfraz, M. and M. F. A. Razzak (2002). “Technical section: An algorithm for automatic capturing of the font outlines”. In: Computers and Graphics, 26.5, pp. 795–804. issn: 0097-8493. Shore, Bradd (Mar. 1991). “Twice-Born, Once Conceived. Meaning Construction and Cultural Cognition”. In: American Anthropologist, new series, 93.1, pp. 9–27.]